# Return a Range not an array from a UDF

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, user-defined-functions

I have created a UDF that merges various value, range and array inputs into a single array. [image: Array Formula]

Hitting <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd> enters it as an array formula meaning `VALUE(F4:G4)` returns an array `{1,#VALUE}`.
My formula stitches values (5, "cat"), ranges ("F6","B2:D6") and even arrays like the one returned by `Value()`, and outputs an array. In the image example that is

```
{0.283982519688569,0.161633595994901,0.521865473646119,0.675542592903341,0.119984734979722,0.842918190377968,0.882045093468071,0.57708164295789,0.305844376489788,0.365360349735221,0.131686453379672,0.557018723742854,0.511032693705543,0.746174410924489,0.863516943921978,5,"cat","Dog",1,#VALUE!}
```

Here's the code:

```
Public Function PROBABLY(ParamArray inputArray() As Variant) As Variant
'Takes a list of parameters, the first of which is an integer, and
Dim inElement As Variant
Dim outputArray() As Variant
Dim subcell As Variant
'convert ranges to values
'creating a new array from the mixture of ranges and values in the input array
ReDim outputArray(0)
For Each inElement In inputArray
'Normal values get copied from the input UDF to an output array, ranges get split up then appended
    If TypeName(inElement) = "Range" Or TypeName(inElement) = "Variant()" Then
        For Each subcell In inElement
            outputArray(UBound(outputArray)) = subcell
            ReDim Preserve outputArray(UBound(outputArray) + 1)
        Next subcell
    'Stick the element on the end of an output array
    Else
        outputArray(UBound(outputArray)) = inElement
        ReDim Preserve outputArray(UBound(outputArray) + 1)
    End If
Next inElement
ReDim Preserve outputArray(UBound(outputArray) - 1)
PROBABLY = outputArray
End Function
```

That was just to show the versatility of the formula with various inputs, in reality I do not want to use this in array formulae. `=PROBABLY(B2:D6,5,"cat")` could be entered normally, *without* <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd>. But the issue is that this returns a `Variant()` -specifically an array*, which makes it hard to use with non array formulae, which often require a `Range` input. So `=CONCAT(PROBABLY(B2:D6,5))` works fine, but `SUMIF(PROBABLY(B2:D6,5),">.5")` does not work, as `SUMIF()` requires a range input. Same reason `SUMIF(VALUE(1,2),">.5")` doesn't work, like my function, value returns an array.

**So the question**: can I *trick* Excel into thinking my array is a range, format it as a Range in some way. Obviously I could take the code out of the UDF and into a sub, then paste my array into a temporary spreadsheet range and tell excel to reference that, but I was hoping to keep the UDF wrapper. (I don't think I can edit the worksheet from within a UDF, although is there some hidden space where I can paste the array and access it from a formula?

Thinking aloud there, any better insights?

**hence `()` after `Variant`*

Comment: A Range object can only point to an existing range on a worksheet - you cannot create a "virtual" Range object which holds values but does not refer to an *actual* range on a worksheet.

Comment: Most Excel functions accept either a range or an array: the SUMIF(s)/COUNTIF(s) families are the main exception. But Tim is correct - there is no easy way of converting an array to a Range (apart from all the other Range properties a Range has a location on a worksheet and an array does not).